# Not able to Iterate through TListView

Tags: delphi

Why is the following code not iterating through the ListView?

```
  for x := 1 to ListView1.Items.Count do
  Begin
    PName := ListView1.Items.Item[i].Caption;
    Variable := ListView1.Items.Item[i].SubItems[0];
    Val := ListView1.Items.Item[i].SubItems[1];
    ToFIle(PName, Variable, Val);
  End;
```

Comment: `for x ...` and `...Item[i]..... You may also want to use indexes `0` to `count -1`

Answer (score 7):

- Your loop variable is `x`, but you use `i` inside the loop body.
- You iterate over the wrong indices. Indices in Delphi are, by convention, zero-based. Your loop should run from `0` to `Count-1`.

Some other points:

- `x` is not a great variable name for an integer index. Use `i` or `index`.
- The `Item` property of `TListItems` is the default property so your code can be simplified by omitting that property.

I would write the code should like so:

```
var
  i: Integer;
  PName, Variable, Val: string;
....
for i := 0 to ListView1.Items.Count-1 do
begin
  PName := ListView1.Items[i].Caption;
  Variable := ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[0];
  Val := ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[1];
  ToFIle(PName, Variable, Val);
end;
```

Or by taking a reference to each item and thus avoiding repetition:

```
var
  i: Integer;
  Item: TListItem;
  PName, Variable, Val: string;
...
for i := 0 to ListView1.Items.Count-1 do
begin
  Item := ListView1.Items[i];
  PName := Item.Caption;
  Variable := Item.SubItems[0];
  Val := Item.SubItems[1];
  ToFIle(PName, Variable, Val);
end;
```

Or by using a `for/in` loop and not needing to care about indexing of the list items:

```
var
  Item: TListItem;
  PName, Variable, Val: string;
...
for Item in ListView1.Items do
begin
  PName := Item.Caption;
  Variable := Item.SubItems[0];
  Val := Item.SubItems[1];
  ToFIle(PName, Variable, Val);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

How is can iterating if you use as loop variable `x`  but inside loop `i`.

And this one:

```
for x := 1 to ListView1.Items.Count do
```

is not correct because you never reach the first element. Please change to:

```
for x := 0 to ListView1.Items.Count - 1 do
  Begin
    PName := ListView1.Items.Item[x].Caption;
    Variable := ListView1.Items.Item[x].SubItems[0];
    Val := ListView1.Items.Item[x].SubItems[1];
    ToFIle(PName, Variable, Val);
  End;
```